# Why can't a knot be embedded in a 2-sphere and what types of knot are allowed on a simplex?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, geometric-topology, knot-theory

I've never studied knot theory so the following proof sorts of trip me up. Please have a look at the questions below.

[image]

[image]

Here are my questions:
1. Why are knots can't be embedded in $S^2$?
2. What is the final stage of dividing the ball into two that we'd get stuck? Initially I thought it'd be something like a layer of simplices covering the "outer" side of the tunnel, but that doesn't seem right.
3. Also, my guess is that the contradiction at the last sentence of the proof arises simply because a simplex has no edge e contained in its interior. Is this correct?

====================================================================

**Edit:** here's the definition of constructibility that we use.

[image]

Comment: A knot embedded in $S^2$ can only be trivial.

Comment: What does constructible mean in this context?

Comment: Apologize for the lack of information. I've added the definition of constructibility to the question.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. I would be tempted to ask what is an example of a non-constructible simplicial complex, but I guess all I have to do is understand the theorem from your question :-)
Although, well, the theorem doesn't claim that such a thing does exist - it may in fact be vacuously true.

Comment: The figure attached is one such example. I was actually after a proof of its nonshellability. But since shellability implies constructibility, my instructor suggests that I should look into its nonconstructibility instead.

Comment: If you need more info you can have a look at the original article here. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00009456

Comment: I can see that there is a trefoil knot shape, but I can't really see how the triangulation is made here.

Comment: The figure is actually a pile of cubes. From what I read, each cube is divided into two prisms, and each of them is divided further into 3 tetrahedra. I think they meant something like this. https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/projects/tetra/sixcube.gif

Comment: I could understand that, but then the knot is not just one edge in this picture. I guess you can maybe distort a simplex so that the knot becomes just one edge, but I'm only half convinced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Any closed curve *embedded* in $S^2$ is a trivial knot. You can consider this as a corollary of the [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem).
2. Note that by definition any constructible complex has only finitely many simplices. Therefore any decreasing sequence of non-empty subcomplexes of maximal dimension has to reach the stage where there are only one, or two, simplices. The contradiction then comes from Point 3 below.
3. You are right, the contradiction is that a simplex has no edge in its interior.